# Auto touch programmable app android

Tags: android

Do you know an app for auto touching the screen for android, programming the time yourself? I know it's not a common question but I need it for a project. I searched a lot and come up with an app to "auto touch" the screen but copying your touches and I want it to touch for example if I set something like this:

In ms

```
touch(100);
touch(542);
touchFrom(1210,1382);
```

I know it's something pretencious but I want to know if there's something like that. If there's nothing then someone knows how to code something like that, something easy?

Comment: You may be the only one that understands that text. What is the specific question? Do you have any code at all?

Comment: No, I never programmed in Java or C or C# but I have knowledge in JS and programming in general

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for an ordinary app to fake input to another app, for security reasons, outside of perhaps on a rooted device.

Test suites using uiautomator can do this, but they are not apps. Accessibilty services may be able to do this, but they are not "something easy".